# Where can I get a JAR to import libcore.io?

Tags: android, exception, import, jar

I want to handle an `GaiException` in my App. The debugger tells me, it lives in the libcore.io package, but importing it yields an error. I guess I need to add an additional JAR to my projct to correctly resolve this type. I've been digging a bit in my android sdk folder, but don't seem to find anything of the kind.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: you can get the source of GaiException.java file from  https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/master/luni/src/main/java/libcore/io/GaiException.java and create a package libcore.io to store that class in it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using android studio you can add this line to your gradle build (under dependencies).

```
compile 'org.robovm:robovm-rt:+'
```

If using Eclipse, check this [Maven link](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robovm/robovm-rt/0.0.9/libcore/io/GaiException.java) and add it however is appropriate.