# Transliteration with Android

Tags: java, android, unicode, icu

I want to transliterate (not translate!) text from arbitrary (as far as possible) languages to English in an Android app. Is there a built-in way?

I've found https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/master/luni/src/main/java/libcore/icu/Transliterator.java but it doesn't seem to be available by default (at least the IDE doesn't find it). Do I simply need to add this code, as suggested by the comment in [Where can I get a JAR to import libcore.io?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14602209/where-can-i-get-a-jar-to-import-libcore-io)?

Alternately, I could add ICU4J to dependencies and follow [icu4j cyrillic to latin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818912/icu4j-cyrillic-to-latin). But this is a very large dependency (though Proguard should help).

Finally, I could easily add transliteration from Cyrillic myself and wait until/if someone actually needs other languages (with obvious drawbacks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the hood, Android has all of ICU4J available under *android.icu*, but only a subset is exposed as public API.  If you want to use a class that isn't exposed, you can write code that uses the class and it should work fine.  However, doing so is not technically supported, so there could be some version of Android somewhere that doesn't have the class for whatever reason and causes your code to break.  (This is unlikely to happen in practice, but possible nonetheless.)

NOTE: The namespace *android.icu* was added in Android 7 Nougat, so it may or may not be usable yet depending on the version of Android you are targeting.

Answer (score 0):

try `compile "org.robovm:robovm-rt:+"`.

robovm-rt has libcore inside. works for me.